# Ubuntu VM (18.04) Unable to Copy/Drag from Guest to Host

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, drag-and-drop, guest-additions

I've tried every option / package install that I was able to find on stackexchange / google. Nothing has worked. I am able to copy paste text into the box, drag files from Windows 7 into Ubuntu, but I can't drag them out (or paste out at all) of the guest without the Ubuntu file explorer freezing until reboot & getting stuck "Dropping data" at 0%. I'm new to Ubuntu so I wouldn't be surprised if I have done something wrong, but I'd really love to be able to get this one simple feature working.

Yes I installed the Guest Additions. Yes both options are set to Bi-directional.
Using a shared folder instead is not ideal. (I don't want to go down a whole new rabbit-hole of getting permissions to use terminal in the media folder) Ubuntu 19 had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `6.1.0=dfsg-3` update because when I installed that, I get same errors you do.

So I've skipped `virtualbox` updates using synaptic package installer. You could try to install the older version that also listen when using `synaptic`, give it a try.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're referring to. When I open Synaptic, what do I want to get?